# having an error with adding a new record in database

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

I found a really good code how to add and modify a record from this website:
http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/

When i wanted to add a new record i get this error on my screen:

> ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.

The error is somewhere around line 43 below

```
1           NEW RECORD
2
3        */
4   // if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
5   else
6   {
7       // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
8       if (isset($_POST['submit']))
9       {
10          // get the form data
11              $titel = htmlentities($_POST['titel'], ENT_QUOTES);
12              $datum = htmlentities($_POST['datum'], ENT_QUOTES);
13              $omschrijving = htmlentities($_POST['omschrijving'], ENT_QUOTES);
14              $begin = htmlentities($_POST['begin'], ENT_QUOTES);
15              $eind = htmlentities($_POST['eind'], ENT_QUOTES);
16          
17          // check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
18          if ($titel == '' || $datum == '' || $omschrijving == '' || $begin == '' || 
19  $eind == '')
20          {
21              // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
22              $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
23              renderForm($titel == '' || $datum == '' || $omschrijving == '' || $begin == 24 '' || $eind == '');
25          }
26          else
27          {
28              // insert the new record into the database
29              if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT famevents (titel, datum, omschrijving, 30 begin, eind) VALUES (?, ?)"))
31              {
32                  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $titel, $datum, $omschrijving, $begin, $eind);
33                  $stmt->execute();
34                  $stmt->close();
35              }
36              // show an error if the query has an error
37              else
38              {
39                  echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
40              }
41              
42              // redirec the user
43              header("Location: beheerevents.php");
44          }
45          
46      }
47      // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
48      else
49      {
50          renderForm();
51      }
52  }
53  
54  // close the mysqli connection
55  $mysqli->close();
```

Personally, i do not see what i do wrong here or what goes wrong.....

On this code there is also a **$_session** going to check that someone is logged in yes or no.

**What i was doing:**

**1.** Modified the code to the data i need to get from my database or send to

**2.** I was trying first to get the `<textarea>` to work in the `<form>` but i couldn't do it so i changed it back to just text input. Still a thing what i like to see to work with the code i have so far.

**3.** Then i saw i was forgotten to modify the code in the section where i add a new record my database tables, like above in the edit section of the code.

---

After that, the error showed up on my screen..... and i am kinda stuck on how i solve that issue...
Hopefully, you can help me with this..

Comment: So you're just getting `echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";`. This is what you shoud look for. Print out the `$stmt->error()` right there. It'll tell you about the SQL parameter count mismatch.

Comment: Okay, now i got this: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /public/sites/www.josdenhertog.nl/familiedenhertog/admin/famevents/records.php on line 200

Might is that because i have a session running in background for checking that the admin is a member of the website?

Comment: Em, use `$mysqli->` then.

Comment: Okay, now it shows this: **Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public/sites/www.josdenhertog.nl/familiedenhertog/admin/famevents/records.php:201) in /public/sites/www.josdenhertog.nl/familiedenhertog/admin/famevents/records.php on line 206**

Comment: The first sentence is operative. Did you read it? And did you look at your SQL query yet?

Comment: Sorry if I look like a douche, but you are using so like a debug tool. And change all the echoes, that makes the modify headers warning.

Comment: @Chelsius Aaah yeah, i used the full names in the echo's on the '$' functions, didn't thought that will harm the rest. BUT i still got something as error what i try to understand: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. <br> Is this because i have a session running in the background?

Comment: INSERT famevents (titel, datum, omschrijving, 30 begin, eind) VALUES (?, ?),you have first, a wrong column name (30 begin) and then you have just 2 values for the 4 or 5 columns defined in the insert. check your queries first

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in statement "INTO" keyword is missing:

```
prepare("INSERT INTO famevents (titel, datum, omschrijving, 30 begin, eind) VALUES (?, ?)"))
```